# TeamCity for Python/Django continuous integration

Tags: python, django, continuous-integration, teamcity

I've set up [TeamCity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeamCity) on a Linux (Ubuntu) box and would like to use it for some of Python/Django projects.

The problem is that I don't really see what to do next - I tried searching for a Python specific build agent for TeamCity but without much of the success.

How can I manage that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Ok, so there's how to get it working with proper TeamCity integration:

Presuming you have TeamCity installed with at least 1 build agent available

1) Configure your build agent to execute

```
manage.py test
```

2) Download and install this plugin for TC http://pypi.python.org/pypi/teamcity-messages

3) You'll have to provide your custom test runner for plugin in (2) to work. It can be straight copy of run_tests from django.test.simple, with only one slight modification: replace line where test runner is called with TeamcityTestRunner, so insted of

```
def run_tests(test_labels, verbosity=1, interactive=True, extra_tests=[]):
    ...
    result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=verbosity).run(suite)
```

use this:

```
def run_tests(test_labels, verbosity=1, interactive=True, extra_tests=[]):
    ...
    result = TeamcityTestRunner().run(suite)
```

You'll have to place that function into a file in your solution, and specify a custome test runner, using Django's TEST_RUNNER configuration property like this:

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'my_site.file_name_with_run_tests.run_tests'
```

Make sure you reference all required imports in your **file_name_with_run_tests**

You can test it by running

```
./manage.py test
```

from command line and noticing that output has changed and now messages like

```
#teamcity....
```

appearing in it.

Answer (score 5):

I have added feature request to TeamCity issue tracker, to make full-featured python support. This is the link: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-25141. If you interested, you can vote for it, and that may force JetBrains to improve python support.

Comment: Good news is that in 2020.2, released just now, this issue is fixed and TeamCity finally has full built-in Python support