# Test coverage in teamcity with Django

Tags: django, continuous-integration, teamcity, django-testing

I have got teamcity working and it builds and runs a custom testrunner (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/teamcity-messages)

I loosly foolowed this post: [TeamCity for Python/Django continuous integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091465/teamcity-for-python-django-continuous-integration)

My run_suite method looks like this:

```
from teamcity import underTeamcity
from teamcity.unittestpy import TeamcityTestRunner
return TeamcityTestRunner().run(suite)
```

I currently use django_coverage with coverage.py and I would like teamcity to get the test coverage data.

I am not bound to teamcity but I prefere using it as a CI server but I can change to another if it is easier.

How can I get the data that ./manage.py test_coverage prints in teamcity?

Answer (score 2):

#### TeamCity Coverage

In TeamCity I cover Django in the following way

Create coverage report by call `make ci_test` command use `Makefile`.

```
VENV_PATH := $(HOME)/venv/bin
PROJ_NAME := my_awesome_project

# ...

ci_test: cover_test cover_report

cover_test:
    $(VENV_PATH)/coverage run --source=$(PROJ_NAME) manage.py test -v 2 --noinput

cover_report:
    $(VENV_PATH)/coverage report -m
    $(VENV_PATH)/coverage html
    $(VENV_PATH)/coverage-badge > htmlcov/coverage.svg
```

The `cover_test` command runs the Django tests, and measures the coverage of the code. The `cover_report` command prints a cover report to the console, and also generates an html report and, using the [coverage-badge](https://github.com/dbrgn/coverage-badge) utility, generates a beautiful badge with the badge code coverage status [image: badge.svg].

After that, artifacts are collected in the TeamCity (tab `General Settings`)

[image: teamcity conf]

They are collected in a tab `Artifacts`

[image: artifacts]

And available on CI server by path:

- `/repository/download/%teamcity.project.id%/%teamcity.build.id%:id/htmlcov /index.html`
- `/repository/download/%teamcity.project.id%/.lastFinished/htmlcov/index.html`

---

#### GitHub report coverage

Finally push GitHub hook to display build coverage state in repo:

Coverage Pending (before build)

```
OWNER="<GITHUB OWNER>";
REPO="<REPO NAME>";
SHA="%build.vcs.number%";

curl "https://api.github.com/repos/$OWNER/$REPO/statuses/$SHA" \
    -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: token <GITHUB API TOKEN>" \
    -d '{
        "state": "pending",
        "description": "Coverage pending.",
        "context": "continuous-integration/coverage"
    }'
```

Coverage badge copy

```
BADGE="/path/to/public/dir/badges/%teamcity.project.id%/%teamcity.build.branch%-coverage.svg"
DIR=$(dirname "${BADGE}")
mkdir -p $DIR
cp -f htmlcov/coverage.svg $BADGE
```

Coverage Finish hook

```
OWNER="<GITHUB OWNER>";
REPO="<REPO NAME>";
SHA="%build.vcs.number%";

REPORT_URL="http://<YOU TEAMCITY DOMAIN>/repository/download/%teamcity.project.id%/%teamcity.build.id%:id/htmlcov/index.html";

COVERAGE=$(cat ./htmlcov/index.html | grep '<span class="pc_cov">' | grep -o '[0-9]\+');

if [ "$COVERAGE" -ge "85" ]; then
    STATUS='success';
else
    STATUS='failure';
fi

curl "https://api.github.com/repos/$OWNER/$REPO/statuses/$SHA" \
    -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: token <GITHUB API TOKEN>" \
    -d '{
        "state": "'$STATUS'",
        "target_url": "'$REPORT_URL'",
        "description": "Coverage '$COVERAGE'%",
        "context": "continuous-integration/coverage"
    }'
```

Result in github:

[image: pending]

[image: fail]

[image: pass]

Blog post about this `ru`: https://maks.live/articles/drugoe/otchety-coverage-v-teamcity/

Comment: Your makefile is not correct. You can check it by running "make -j 8". cover_report should depend on cover_test because it needs to be run AFTER it.

Answer (score 1):

I use [teamcity-nose](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/teamcity-nose) with the following configuration in settings.py:

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
NOSE_ARGS = ['-v', '-s', '--rednose', '--with-selenium',]

if os.getenv('TEAMCITY_PROJECT_NAME') is not None:
   # whatever special teamcity settings you might have go here
```

My build step that does the testing looks like this:

```
. /opt/teamcity/virtualenvs/myproj/bin/activate
 dropdb test_myproj-teamcity &> /dev/null # bug that is not destroying database
 manage.py test
```

My project's manage.py is on the path (I install in the virtualenv bin via setup.py)
so you will have to add the path if you do otherwise.

I never managed to add the coverage in the test itself as there are problems with package versioning, so with the latest coverage package i Just added it in an extra build step:

```
. /opt/teamcity/virtualenvs/myproj/bin/activate
 coverage html --include=myproj/*.*
 cloc . --out=./htmlcov/cloc.txt
```

You can then add a tab that includes the coverage html if you add this to your artifact:

```
./htmlcov/
```

I also add a tab with the line counter too, you will need to have cloc or the linecounter of your choice installed.

I also have an extra build configuration for deploying to staging server once a night via fab (just activate and fab as usual), and an extra build for automatically installing pip requirements if the pip files change, by adding this to the triggering rules for the "pip install -r requirements.pip" build:

```
+:**.pip
```

And I add this to my test build so that it doesn't run when pip and some other files change that don't effect the build test:

```
+:.
-:**.pip
-:*fabfile.py
-:*myproj/conf/*
+:*myproj/conf/teamcity/*
```