# Python Test coverage in teamcity

Tags: python, testing, teamcity, coverage.py

I want to setup python test coverage report in TeamCity Professional 2021.2.3. I am using python coverage module which i have installed in my conda environment. My testsuit contains mostly pytests and some unittests. I read on TeamCity official page that for pytest, coverage module works builtin in teamcity. To setup coverage in teamcity, I have followed this post : [Test coverage in teamcity with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448891/test-coverage-in-teamcity-with-django)

[image: Below is my python tests setup]

[image: And Build step setup]

With this setup, my tests seem to be running fine. However, i don't see any coverage tab when i open the successful test run. Also i don't see any html file in the Artifacts tab.

[image: Test run result]

My question is why don't i see the coverage tab and the html files in the Artifacts tab. I am missing something in my setup?